# How to convert ansible string to float and use that value to compare with float value

Tags: deployment, ansible

I want to convert `Ansible` `string` value to `float` and compare with another `float` value

In my `ini` file `bin_version=6.5.17` I want to compare `bin_version` with 1 decimal value(6.5 >= 6.7) so I'm splitting it with 1 decimal value `bin_version.split('.')[:2]` and joining it with float 
`"{{bin_version.split('.')[:2] | join('.')|float}}"`

But it's not working as expected with `when` condition `when: version >= 6.7`, Does it float conversion(`|float`) really working here ?

```
tasks:
  - set_fact:
      version: "{{bin_version.split('.')[:2] | join('.')|float}}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{version}}"
    when: version >= 6.7
```

`task` should be only executed when `version >= 6.7`

But

Case: 1: Pass

```
  when: version >= 6.7 // 6.5 >= 6.7
```

Expected result is task should be skipped but it's executing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to compare as below

```
when: bin_version is version('6.7', '>=')
```

Comment: Awesome, Do you thing any improvement can be done in the above script ?

Comment: I think you need not convert to float.

Comment: Yes you're right float type conversion is not required. Thanx

Comment: failed. The error was: Version comparison: 'StrictVersion' object has no attribute 'version'\n\n I'm getting this error.